# Yii2-mongodb: How can i write update query in yii2 specific to php mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

I am recently studing yii2. I am using mongodb at backend database. I am confused for the update query i found in the documentation

```
 public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $query = new Query;
    $row = $query->from('item')
        where(['_id' => $id]) // implicit typecast to [[\MongoId]]
        ->one();
    ...
}
```

I am writing php specific mongodb query as follows...

```
    $update = array('$set' => array("status" => 'read', "agencyStatus" => 'unread'));
    $where = array("_id" => new MongoId($id));

    $mongoDb->update($where, $update);
```

how the syntax would be in yii2 specific mongodb???

Answer (score 0):

You can generate Mongo model using gii([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1urmws7hz5Q)) and do in your controller something like:

```
    $item = Item::find()->where(["_id" => new MongoId($id)]);
    $item->status = 'read';
    $item->agencyStatus= 'unread';
    $item->save();
```

Comment: It isn't working for me. throws Exception (MongoDB Exception) 'yii\mongodb\Exception' with message '127.0.0.1:27017: E11000 duplicate key error index: mydb.users.$_id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('55584f3371352d8a92b7acda') }